# Group by with null columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get group of column values with comma separated including Null values of Group by columns. Group by treats NUll values as 
separate group.

Let us say there is an input_table:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|      obj1      obj2       obj3      fail_msg       |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                    |
|        A                               msg1        |
|        A          B            C       msg2        |
|        A          B            D       msg3        |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

i want to get the results as below from input table.

Results:

```
----------------------------------
          A         B            C      msg1, msg2
          A         B            D      msg1, msg3
```

Similar to Listagg function , but group by with Null values.

Example:

```
select LISTAGG(fail_msg, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY fail_msg) failure_ message
    from input_table group by  obj1, obj2, obj3
```

But this query is not merging null values in listagg()

can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit your question and show what you mean by "merging null values in `listagg()`.  `listagg()` ignores `NULL` values by design.

Comment: It isn't clear how you would arrive at your result by aggregating.

Comment: Please read the post now. I find tough time in editing.

Comment: I understand that when no `obj2` is filled in row it means this row is aplicable to any `obj2` Is it?

Comment: yes. Similarly for obj3 too.

Comment: Basically i want to produce fail_msg at object 'c' level with concatenating the predecessor alone fail_msg example .For object c, a and b are predecessors

Comment: Use nvl() or coalesce() to replace null values with empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

That's very bad code but seem to do what you need:

```
with d as (
  select 'A' as o1, 'B' as o2, 'C' as o3, 'm1' as m from dual union all
  select 'A' as o1, 'B' as o2, 'D' as o3, 'm3' as m from dual union all
  select 'A' as o1, null as o2, null as o3, 'm2' as m from dual
)
select o1, o2, o3, listagg(m, ',') within group (order by o1)  from 
(select distinct nvl(d1.o1, d2.o1) as o1, nvl(d1.o2, d2.o2) as o2, nvl(d1.o3, d2.o3) as o3, d1.m
  from d d1 inner join d d2 on (nvl(d1.o1,d2.o1) = nvl(d2.o1, d1.o1) and nvl(d1.o2,d2.o2) = nvl(d2.o2, d1.o2) and nvl(d1.o3,d2.o3) = nvl(d2.o3, d1.o3)))
  group by o1, o2, o3;
```

Comment: That seems a little specific to the exact values in the table, doesn't it?  If you could know that those were the specific values in the table, why would you write a query at all?

Comment: yes, the exact values are object id's , which are hibernate generated .Dont know ahead.

Comment: Why? In with I've just generated data. Solution is not specific fopr values.

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` alone won't yield this result no matter what you do, because it assigns each row to one and only one group.  (There are ways to get summary rows, or multiple grouping sets in one query, but still those don't help here...)

The odds are you can do this more easily outside of SQL; but if you must do it in a query then you could try an approach like the following.

Note that this query is good enough for the example you gave; if your real requirements are more complicated, you may have to expand on these basic ideas.  Also note that I'm showing the logic incrementally for clear explanation, but just the last query is what you'd want:

So first we can get a list of the messages with NULL values.

```
select *
  from input_table
 where obj2 is NULL
   and obj3 is NULL
```

We need to join this with the list of `obj2` and `obj3` values that exist for the given `obj1` value; this is to create individual message records to apply in each group.

```
select null_list.obj1, obj_list.obj2, obj_list.obj3, null_list.fail_msg
  from            input_table null_list
       inner join (select distinct obj1, obj2, obj3
                     from input_table) as obj_list
               on null_list.obj1 = obj_list.obj1
```

Now combine that with the list of messages that didn't have null values

```
select null_list.obj1, obj_list.obj2, obj_list.obj3, null_list.fail_msg
  from            input_table null_list
       inner join (select distinct obj1, obj2, obj3
                     from input_table) as obj_list
               on null_list.obj1 = obj_list.obj1
UNION ALL
select *
  from input_table
 where obj2 is not null
   and obj3 is not null
```

(Note that the above only handles records where obj2 and obj3 either both are null, or neither are null.  This is part of where I'm only addressing the example and you'd need to add more logic if you need to deal with different combinations of columns being null.  That can get messy fast; like I said, SQL isn't *really* the tool for this job.)

Well now you have it as a list of messages applied to specific combinations of obj1,obj2,obj3 and a simple LILSTAGG should get you the rest of the way there.